# C++ delete и delete[]

Tags: c++, delete

Ясное дело, что по **Стандарту** вызовы **malloc()/free()*, **new/delete** и **new[]/delete[]** должны быть строго парными, иначе неопределенное поведение.

Хотя я и видел в очень крупных и серьезных проектах что-то вроде:

```
float *f = new float[count];
// ...
delete f;
```

Разработчики обосновывали такую запись так: мол, тип элементарный, деструктора не имеет, можно делать **delete** и не париться, за несколько лет разработки с этим ни разу не возникло проблем.

*...но мы-то с вами знаем, что это неопределенное поведение, и в очередную пятницу тринадцатого компилятор решит скомпилировать код запуска всех ядерных ракет...*

Меня беспокоит пара других вопросов:

1)

```
Type *f = new Type[1];
delete f;
```

Это неопределенное поведение?

2)

```
struct Type
{
    int a, b, c;
    float values[10];
};

Type *f = new Type[count];
free(f);
```

Даже если **Type** не содержит деструктора и динамических данных, например, если это структура/класс из нескольких объектов элементарных типов, это все равно неопределенное поведение?

Answer (score 7):

1. Формально - да, неопределенное, так как для выделения вызывается оператор `new` для массива, пусть и из одного элемента, а `delete` - нет.
2. Уж это точно неопределенное, потому как `new/delete` и `malloc/free` вообще могут использовать разные механизмы работы с памятью.

*"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

См. также [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1066795/195342).

Comment: Понял, благодарю.

Answer (score 4):

1.

На первый взгляд в этом примере:

```
Type *f = new Type[1];
delete f;
```

Компилятор может понять, что запрашивается один элемент.

Но в общем случае оператор new не анализирует количество запрашиваемых элементов массива хотя бы потому, что в общем случае это количество может быть известно только в рантайме. Поэтому

```
Type *f = new Type[1];
delete f;
```

однозначно неправильно. Ведь на месте единицы может быть переменная, значение которой вводит пользователь.

Например:

```
int size;
cin>>size;

Type *f = new Type[size];
delete f;
```

  2.

Однозначно нельзя запрашивать память new а освобождать free. Это вообще из другой оперы. Парный оператор для new это delete.