# Удаление динамически выделенного объекта класса в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Это работает:

```cpp
map<int, bool>* m = new map<int, bool>;
delete (m + 0);
```

Это не работает:

```cpp
map<int, bool>* ms = new map<int, bool>[4];
delete (ms + 0); // для примера удаляю только первый элемент, а не весь массив
```

Почему?

Comment: Я не эксперт, но вроде должно быть delete[], потому что это массив

Comment: Нет, я для примера удаляю только первый элемент.

Comment: ну тогда попробуй delete ms[0], потому что ms это не просто первый элемент, а указатель на весь массив

Comment: `ms[0]` - это то же самое, что и `(ms + 0)`. Пробовал, та же ошибка.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия попробуйте теперь последний элемент удалить. И попробуйте засунуть что-то в map перед удалением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главный вопрос - что значит "не работает"? Судя по всему, вы после этого пытаетесь работать с `ms[1]`, и получаете неприятности?

Удалить "только один элемент" - затея вообще совершенно бредовая. Ибо память выделяется целыми кусками, и ровно такими же освобождается. Нельзя выделить память в 200 байт, а потом сказать - нет, вторые 100 мне не нужны, царь знает, что делает - забирайте! Просто потому, что это так не работает :)

Если бы вы захотели удалить какой-то другой, не первый элемент - тут стандарт говорит однозначно - в `delete` можно засунуть только тот адрес, который получен через `new`.

> In a single-object delete expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (6.6.2) representing a base class of such an object (11.6). If not, the behavior is undefined.  (7.6.2.8.2)

А при удалении массивов надо `delete[]`, и только `delete[]`. Хотя бы для того, чтобы были вызваны все деструкторы :)

И вообще - в стандарте четко сказано (7.6.2.7.10):

> If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function’s name is operator new and the deallocation function’s name is operator delete. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function’s name is operator new[] and the deallocation function’s name is operator delete[].

Конкретная реализация вообще может `delete[]` реализовывать не так, как просто `delete` (в смысле служебных структур менеджера памяти). Например, `new[]` может выделять дополнительную память под запись количества элементов, или они могут записываться в памяти перед возвращаемым указателем, так что при вызове не соответствующего оператора он может просто обрушить служебные записи менеджера памяти.

Словом, может произойти все, что угодно.